# Angular CLI script not always loaded as utf8

Tags: javascript, angular, utf-8, webpack, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4 application that has been internationalized.  In the scripts section of the angular-cli.json file I am including a JavaScript file per culture that has the internationalization information for that culture, including translated strings.  I am having trouble with the Japanese file that includes UTF-8 characters.

If I access the application using the base URL, the strings are displayed correctly.  If I instead access the application using a specific page (say my.ui/welcome) then the UTF-8 strings from the Japanese file are corrupt, like they are not loaded in UTF-8.

The culture script is inside of scripts.bundle.js on the server and has the correct UTF-8 characters there.  However, when the scripts.bundle.js file is viewed through the browser when the characters are corrupt on screen, they are also corrupt in the file.

From angular-cli.json:

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/@infor/sohoxi/dist/js/sohoxi.js",
    "../node_modules/@infor/sohoxi/dist/js/cultures/ja-JP"
  ],
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this and how to correct it?

Comment: what IDE are you using?